# Stata Regex for 'standalone' numbers in string

Tags: regex, stata

I am trying to remove a specific pattern of numbers from a string using the `regexr` function in Stata. I want to remove any pattern of numbers that are not bounded by a character (other than whitespace), or a letter. For example, if the string contained `t370` or `6-test` I would want those to remain. It's only when I have numbers next to each other.

```
clear 
input id str40 string
1 "9884 7-test 58 - 489"
2 "67-tty 783 444"
3 "j3782 3hty"
end
```

I would like to end up with:

```
ID     string
1      7-test
2      67-tty
3      j37b2 3hty
```

I've tried different regex statements to find when numbers are wrapped in a word boundary: `regexr(string, "\b[0-9]+\b", "")`; in addition to manually adding the white space `" [0-9]+"` which will only replace if the pattern occurs in the middle, not at the start of a string. If it's easier to do this without regex expressions that's fine, I was just trying to become more familiar.

Comment: Something like `\s*(-\s*)?(?<!\S)[0-9]+(?!\S)` could do, but there will be leading whitespaces left if the match occurs at the start of string.

Comment: What criterion leads you to ignore  `-`? You've said you don't want "words" that are pure numbers, but `-` isn't such.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I get an error: `regexp: ?+* follows nothing`. Do I add anything further between the quotations of the command?

Comment: Ah, no, it means Stata regex does not support lookarounds, or at least lookbehinds.

Comment: I would tend to loop over the words of string accepting or rejecting one at  a time.

Comment: Agree, `split` your strings at a white space and then concatenate the parts that are not only a number or "-". Unfortunately Stata's `regexm` family is lacking compared to regular expressions in other languages/software...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Stata does allow that, but the unicode regex engine would be needed, i.e. `ustrregexra(string, "\s*(-\s*)?(?<!\S)[0-9]+(?!\S)", "")`

Comment: Very cool @Wouter, I did not know `ustrregexm()` supports lookaround assertions. I think you should post that as a formal answer it is very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following up on the loop suggesting from the comments, you could do something like the following:

```
clear 
input id str40 string
1 "9884 7-test 58 - 489"
2 "67-tty 783 444"
3 "j3782 3hty"
end

gen N_words = wordcount(string) // # words in each string
qui sum N_words 
global max_words = r(max)  // max # words in all strings

split string, gen(part) parse(" ") // split string at space (p.s. space is the default)

gen string2 = ""
forval i = 1/$max_words {
    * add in parts that contain at least one letter
    replace string2 = string2 + " " + part`i' if regexm(part`i', "[a-zA-Z]") & !missing(string2)
    replace string2 = part`i' if regexm(part`i', "[a-zA-Z]") & missing(string2)
}

drop part* N_words
```

where the result would be

```
. list

     +----------------------------------------+
     | id                 string      string2 |
     |----------------------------------------|
  1. |  1   9884 7-test 58 - 489       7-test |
  2. |  2         67-tty 783 444       67-tty |
  3. |  3             j3782 3hty   j3782 3hty |
     +----------------------------------------+
```

Note that I have assumed that you want all words that contain at least one letter. You may need to adjust the `regexm` here for your specific use case.